# method group is not assignable to Icomparer<DateTime>

Tags: c#, .net

I write `Foo<T>(IComparer<T> comp)`

I want to call it with

```
Foo<DateTime> (DateTime.compare)
```

but i get this error:

> method group is not assignable to `IComparer<DateTime>`

how can I solve this?

TIA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method expects an instance of `IComparer<T>`, not a delegate. You need to create a class that implements `IComparer<DateTime>`:

```
public class DateTimeComparer : IComparer<DateTime>
{
    public int Compare(DateTime x, DateTime y)
    {
        return x.Compare(y);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could change the method so that it expects a `Comparison<DateTime>`:

```
void Foo<T>(Comparison<T> comparison)
```

Then you could pass `DateTime.Compare` directly as a parameter.

Since there are more methods that require an `IComparer<T>` than a `Comparison<T>`, I use a helper class to make an `IComparer<T>` from a `Comparison<T>`:

```
public class ComparisonComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
{
    private readonly Comparison<T> _comparison;

    public ComparisonComparer(Comparison<T> comparison)
    {
        _comparison = comparison;
    }

    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        return _comparison(x, y);
    }
}
```

You can use it as follows:

```
Foo(new ComparisonComparer(DateTime.Compare));
```